# Converting HTML list from json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a problem with my code when listing countries from json file:

My HTML

```
<div id="country">country</div>
```

My JS Code

```
$.getJSON( "country.js", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "#country" );
});
```

Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/4719/)

Comment: provide your country.js content.

Comment: Its in fiddle itself. Find in external resource.

Comment: problem is your file is `.js` and you are doing `$.getJSON` change the file to `.json`.

Comment: in which fiddle you updated?

Comment: Sorry forget to update it here. Now updated in above link. Thanks

Comment: if you'll see your fiddle properly it gives a error, you should remove the very first `{` and last `}` Then it'll be a proper json.

Comment: Thanks. Thats was one of my try. changed it now.

Comment: can you just remove `var countryList = ` and just have JSON like `[{....}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json source is wrong.

1. remove `var countryList =`
2. Find `code: 'TF'`  and change it to `"code": "TF"`
3. You accessed wrong variable.

   `items.push( "<li id='" + val.countryCode + "'>" + val.countrName + "</li>" );`

Comment: Missed end of line ")}". Thanks lot woking :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma in your json source.

Find this line:

{"countrName" : "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "dialCode" : "+1 340", "countryCode" : "VI"}

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with your generated json, I fixed that one and updated **file will be found [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=838052F41207D240!676&authkey=!APF_bpZlvROJNOI&ithint=file%2Cjson)**

Whats make your file invalid is [image]

For better understanding below is the code that I tested

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country">country</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON( "country.json", function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, row ) {

            items.push( "<li id='" + row.countryCode + "'>" + row.countrName + "</li>" );
        });

        $( "<ul/>", {
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "#country" );
    });
</script>
```

**N.B:** I changed each loop to make it working. Please look into that closely. Also if your country list comes dynamically from any script. Please make that error fixed for generated JSON

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is remove **var countryList =**  from your json file.

use json like a service anyone can use easily.

by writing **var countryList** this json will limited to javascript only.

Preferred solution is:
read file using $get
like

```
var items = [];
$.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100011869/country.js", function(data) {
    var gList = eval("(" + contryList + ")");

    for (var i = 0; i < gList.length; i++) {
        items.push("<li id='" + gList[i].countryCode + "'>" + gList[i].countrName + "</li>");
    }


    alert(items.join(""));
});
```